# Автоматическое исправление коммитов

Tags: git, bash, perl, shell, git-commit

Всем привет

Задача такая: 
Нужно внести изменения в коммиты.

1. Удалить из коммитов строчку по шаблону, если она есть
2. Имя автора нужно переписать с большой буквы
3. Исправить домен почты

Пример:

```
Author: bob <bob@b57f2ef1-5141-491f-aab4-af533bc7c3cb>
Date:   Sun Jan 10 12:32:31 2016 +0000

    Initial commit   

    *строчка которую надо удалить*
```

Что требуется:

```
Author: Bob <bob@primer.com> <======== Bob с большой буквы и правильный домен
Date:   Sun Jan 10 12:32:31 2016 +0000

    Initial commit

==== удалена строчка соответствующая шаблону ====
```

Попробовал делать через git rebase -i и git commit --amend, но коммитов достаточное количество, чтобы захотелось как-то ускорить процесс.
Хотелось бы услышать возможные решения

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/750182

Comment: И вообще искать примеры git filter-branch

Comment: А вообще это похоже на импорт из svn. Может его проще сделать сразу с правильными данными (я не знаю возможно ли это)?

Comment: ссылку глянул, у меня 3 имени, для каждого надо ифы писать?
просто хотелось бы какое-нибудь такое решение
if 
sed ^[a-z]* => ^[A-Z]*

Comment: *удалил нечитабельно*

Comment: Прочитайте доку. Это shell-скрипт. Можете написать его как угодно

Answer (score 2):

Как вам правильно подсказал @AlexeyTen, нужно использовать [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)

Для изменения сообщений служит `--msg-filter`. Вот пример из документации.

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter '
    sed -e "/^git-svn-id:/d"
'
```

Как видно, тут вызывается внешняя программа `sed`. Аналогично и для `--commit-filter` можно вызывать внешнюю программу или скрипт.